# Indefinite article absence in scheduled actions

Tags: articles

This morning I saw a sign at a metrostation "Train arrives in a minute". The question is: Why the article "a" is omitted before the word "train"? I would say "A train arrives..." because 1) train here is singular 2) a train that arrives is the one of many others. Where am I wrong?

Comment: It's common to omit articles from signs, newspaper headlines and the like, to save space. The meaning is perfectly clear without them.

Comment: It's a compressed style used for signs and notices. It's a little bit like the style used for news headlines [I now see KB has just pointed this out]. If present, the article would probably not be *a*, because that sounds as though some random train is arriving, whereas it's a specific train we have in mind. If we put in the article *the* we would probably add *next* - so *the next train arrives in 1 minute*, *next train in 1 minute* and *train arrives in minute* are all fine. On the other hand *a train arrives in 1 minute* is very strange, and *the train arrives in 1 minute* is a bit strange.

Comment: How do you know it isn't definite?

Answer (score 2):

As the text in signs and important notices has to be **precise**, to **easily and quickly read by people**, it is not always a grammatically complete sentence.
As the phrase "*Trains leaves in a minute*" is delivering the meaning clearly, extra words are omitted to keep it short.

You can notice the pattern in road signs or newspaper headlines too.
E.g, "Men at work" is a common road sign. The complete version could be "Please be careful, men are working on the road here", but the precise, two-worded phrase is more easier and quicker to be read by people on the move, and is clearly understandable, so all the extra words are omitted.

(On the side not, the article "the" would have been use to complete to, not "a", as a specific train is being discussed, that is to be leaving in a minute.)